# Yii2 ЧПУ как указать в route полученный параметр из запроса?

Tags: yii, yii2

Не мог найти или правильно сформировать вопрос. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Мой url: site.ru/module/controller/?handler=action

Я хочу, чтобы было перенаправление на site.ru/module/controller/action
Пытался в правилах указать вот такое

```
[
      'pattern' => 'module/controller/<handler:\w+>',
      'route' => 'module/controller/<handler>'
]
```

Подскажите, как правильно написать правило и можно ли использовать в route?

Comment: Возможно вам просто нужно настроить ЧПУ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525320/enable-clean-url-in-yii2 ?

Answer (score 2):

backend/config/main.php

frontend/config/main.php
в этих местах надо написать

```
'request' => [
 'baseUrl' => '',
],

'urlManager' => [
 'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
 'showScriptName' => false,
 'rules' => [
   '' => 'site/index',
   '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
    ],
  ],
```

Это у меня fronted

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [




    'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => '',
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '' => 'site/index',
            '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
        ],
    ],



    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
    /*
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
    */
],
'params' => $params,
];
```